# how to get distinct data from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table like this:
[image]

I want to get distinct `hostel_name` from table according to date.if the date is same then only distinct name is fetched but if date change then same hostel_name also fetched.just like uper image.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `group by hostel_name, date`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `group by` clause on `hostel_name` and `date`

```
SELECT id,date,type,hostel_name,block_id,hostel_charge from <table_name> group by hostel_name,date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY to group the data based on DATE and HOSTEL_NAME. But, if you are only interested in getting distinct DATE and HOSTEL_NAME use this,

SELECT DISTINCT DATE, HOSTEL_NAME FROM <TABLE_NAME> ORDER BY DATE